# How can I infinitely repeat a jQuery Animation

Tags: jquery

How can I get this animation to repeat infinitely:

```
$(window).load(function () {

$("#ani-image").fadeIn(600, function () {
$("#ani-bluescreen").fadeIn(300);
$("#ani-text").fadeIn(300);
$("#ani-text").animate({ marginLeft: "400px",}, 400 );  
});  

var delay = 5000;

$("#ani-bg").delay(delay).fadeIn(1000, function () {
$("#ani-image-2").fadeIn(300); 
$("#ani-bluescreen-2").fadeIn(300); 
$("#ani-text-2").fadeIn(300);
$("#ani-text-2").animate({ marginLeft: "400px",}, 400 );
});

var delay = 10000;

$("#ani-bg-2").delay(delay).fadeIn(1000, function () {
$("#ani-image-3").fadeIn(300);
$("#ani-bluescreen-3").fadeIn(300);       
$("#ani-text-3").fadeIn(300);
$("#ani-text-3").animate({ marginLeft: "400px",}, 400 );
});

var delay = 15000;

$("#ani-bg-3").delay(delay).fadeIn(1000, function () {
});
});
```

Comment: That appears to be jQuery but it would be helpful if you specified.

Answer (score 1):

From http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers

```
everyTime(interval : Integer | String, [label = interval : String], fn : Function, [times = 0 : Integer])
```

> everyTime will add the defined
>   function (fn) as a timed event to run
>   at a given time interval (interval)
>   for a given number of times (times).
>   If times is set to 0, the number of
>   times the method is called is
>   unbounded. A label is also set for the
>   given timed event either to the
>   provided string (label) or to the
>   string representation of the interval
>   provided. Additionally, the interval
>   can be defined by using a string such
>   as "3s" for 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it all in a `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(function () {
  $("#ani-image").fadeIn(600, function () {
    $("#ani-bluescreen").fadeIn(300);
    $("#ani-text").fadeIn(300);
    $("#ani-text").animate({
      marginLeft: "400px",
    }, 400);
  });

  var delay = 5000;

  $("#ani-bg").delay(delay).fadeIn(1000, function () {
    $("#ani-image-2").fadeIn(300);
    $("#ani-bluescreen-2").fadeIn(300);
    $("#ani-text-2").fadeIn(300);
    $("#ani-text-2").animate({
      marginLeft: "400px",
    }, 400);
  });

  var delay = 10000;

  $("#ani-bg-2").delay(delay).fadeIn(1000, function () {
    $("#ani-image-3").fadeIn(300);
    $("#ani-bluescreen-3").fadeIn(300);
    $("#ani-text-3").fadeIn(300);
    $("#ani-text-3").animate({
      marginLeft: "400px",
    }, 400);
  });

  var delay = 15000;

  $("#ani-bg-3").delay(delay).fadeIn(1000, function () {});
}, 5000); // 5 seconds
```

Comment: This is starting the animation with 5 second delay, but isn't repeating. Is there something I'm missing.

Comment: then it repeats it again. every 5 seconds

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, for me it's not repeating:http://pachecosalon.com/jqtest/

Comment: @Stucky, can you put thta into a fiddle so i can play with it?